# For loop, wildcard and conditional statement

Tags: bash, for-loop, if-statement

I don't really know what am I supposed to do with it.

For each file in the /etc directory whose name starts with the o or l and the second letter and the second letter of the name is t or r, display its name, size and type ('file'/'directory'/'link'). Use: wildcard, for loop and conditional statement for the type.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
etc_dir=$(ls -a /etc/ | grep '^o|^l|^.t|^.r')
for file in $etc_dir
do
    stat -c '%s-%n' "$file"
done
```

I was thinking about something like that but I have to use if statement.

Comment: You can iterate over a file glob directly instead of using a variable: `for file in [ol][tr]*`. Also, your `grep` says "or" not "and".

Comment: The idea of this community is not to solve your homework for you. If you ever want to become a self-sustained software engineer, you have to learn to break problems down into smaller pieces and tackle them one by one.

Comment: Of course I don't want anyone to do my homework for me. I need a hint. I started with something ;) It's not like I hadn't got anything.

Answer (score 2):

You may reach the goal by using `find` command.

###### This will search through all subdirectories.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
_dir='/etc'

find "${_dir}" -name "[ol][tr]*" -exec stat -c '%s-%n' {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

###### To have control on searching in subdirectories, you may use `-maxdepth` flag, like in the below example it will search only the files and directories name in the `/etc` dir and don't go through the subdirectories.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
_dir='/etc'

find "${_dir}" -maxdepth 1 -name "[ol][tr]*" -exec stat -c '%s-%n' {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

###### You may also use `-type f` OR `-type d` parameters to filter finding only Files OR Directories accordingly (if needed).

```bash
#!/bin/bash
_dir='/etc'

find "${_dir}" -name "[ol][tr]*" -type f -exec stat -c '%s-%n' {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

## Update #1

Due to your request in the comments, this is a long way but used `for` loop and `if` statement.

Note: I'd strongly recommend to review and practice the commands used in this script instead of just copy and pasting them to get the score ;)

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Set the main directory path.
_mainDir='/etc'

# This will find all files in the $_mainDir (ignoring errors if any) and assign the file's path to the $_files variable.
_files=$(find "${_mainDir}" 2>/dev/null)

# In this for loop we will 
# loop over all files
# identify the poor filename from the whole file path
# and IF the poor file name matches the statement then run & output the `stat` command on that file.

for _file in ${_files} ;do
  _fileName=$(basename ${_file})
  if [[ "${_fileName}" =~  ^[ol][tr].* ]] ;then
    stat -c 'Size: %s , Type: %n ' "${_file}"
  fi
done

exit 0
```

Comment: My professor told us to use if statement and loop for

Comment: @livist recursively whithin all subdirectories of `/etc` or not?

Comment: Yes, within all

Comment: @livist  I have updated my answer, please review it (Update #1) and try to research and learn more about the commands used.

Also please accept my answer as the correct one if it satisfies your request.

Answer (score 0):

You should break-down you problems into multiple pieces and tackle them one by one.

First, try and build an expression that finds the right files. If you were to execute your regex expression in a shell:

```
ls -a /etc/ | grep '^o|^l|^.t|^.r'
```

You would immediately see that you don't get the right output. So the first step would be to understand how grep works and fix the expression to:

```
ls -a /etc/ | grep '^[ol][tr]*'
```

Then, you have the file name, and you need the size and a textual file type. The size is easy to obtain using a `stat` call.

But, you soon realize you cannot ask stat to provide a textual format of the file type with the `-f` switch, so you probably have to use an if clause to present that.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work :/ It display files which start with O or L, but the second letter isn't T or R.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls -dp /etc/@(o|l)@(t|r)* | grep -v '/$'
```

Explanation:

- `shopt extglob` - enable extended globbing (https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+extglob)
- `ls -d` - list directories names, not their content
- `ls -dp` - and add `/` at the end of each directory name
- `@(o|l)@(t|r)` - `o` or `l` once (`@`), and then `t` or `r` once
- `grep -v '/$'` - remove all lines containing `/` at the end

Of course, Vab's `find` solution is better that this `ls`:

```
find /etc -maxdepth 1 -name "[ol][tr]*" -type f -exec stat {} \;
```